# How to keep MEAN (stack) running?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, mean-stack, mean

I'm using grunt to run the MEAN project on Ubuntu, but when I close the putty (I use putty to connect Ubuntu server from my PC), it would close the program too.

My question is how can I keep MEAN running?

Update: `nohub grunt &` stops after I close putty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various node based process managers which can serve your task. My favorite is `pm2` (http://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

Package managers allow your program to keep running even in case of hiccups. They can watch your project directories for any changes that you might push to them and restart servers based on those changes.

Other favorite is `forever` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever).

Answer (score 0):

you need to run the command in background and I would also recommend to use nohup so:

```
nohup grunt &
```

should do the trick.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

Comment: `nohub grunt &` stops after I close putty

Comment: @DotKu nohup instead of nohub!

Comment: Sorry, it was my typo, but I mean `nohup`

Answer (score 0):

NODE_ENV=staging nohup node appStag.js &
 You can use the above command to run node server
 and you can get the above environment using process.env.NODE_ENV

Answer (score 0):

I found a npm package called forever is a good solution, I use forever to run the program right now; and it works perfect with putty.